# Simple array_diff not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. 
The first one is $teach_array and the second one is $langs_array.

Their respective values are: 
$teach_array : `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`
$langs_array : `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )`

Im trying to return a new array containing all the entries from $teach_array that are not present in $langs_array. 
So the end result should be: `Array ( [0] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`

I have tried using a couple of methods including :

#### Option 1

```
$result = array_diff($teachArray, $language_1d_array);
```

This still returns all the values of $teach_array.

#### Option 2

```
 $result = array_diff_key($teachArray, $language_1d_array);
```

However, this only returns `Array ( [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )` which is not correct.

#### Option 3

```
$result = array_values(array_diff_key($teachArray, $language_1d_array));
```

This returns the same result as Option 2. I also tried using only array_diff instead of array_diff_key and it returns the same result as Option 1.

I did a var_dump on both of my arrays and here is the result.

$teach_array : `array(5) { [0]=> string(5) " 1 " [1]=> string(5) " 2 " [2]=> string(5) " 3 " [3]=> string(5) " 4 " [4]=> string(5) " 5 " }` 
$lang_array : `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }`

Comment: Well, the functions are working as they are supposed to. Let's see if we can find a function that does what you want.

Comment: `array_diff` works just fine for this. It should produce the output you want.

Comment: take a good look at your array names. you use different names and 1d which may need to be id. so maybe the error is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hope you have already found the solution, but just in case I want to point you on following.

> Blockquote
>   I did a var_dump on both of my arrays and here is the result. 
>   $teach_array : array(5) { [0]=> string(5) " 1 " [1]=> string(5) " 2 " [2]=> string(5) " 3 " [3]=> string(5) " 4 " [4]=> string(5) " 5 " } 
>   $lang_array : array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }

No single value from $teach_array matches any value of $lang_array.
Because there are differently formatted values, one array contains whitespaces before and after the value you want to match `" 2 "`.

`var_dump($teach_array) => array(5) { [0]=> string(5) " 4 "  ... }`
`var_dump($lang_array) => array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "2"  ... }`

I guess you have some whitespaces included. Please try again with:

```
$diff = array_diff(array_map('trim', $teach_array), $lang_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

PHPTester just tested yours, works fine for me..?

```
$teachArray =[1,2,3,4,5];
$langsarray =[2,3];
$result = array_diff($teachArray,$langsarray);
print_r($result);
```

works and prints 1, 4, 5 for me.

BUT...here's a solution for what you're trying to acquire: the values in teacher array that are not in langs

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($teach_array as $item){    // Loop the teacher_array
  if(!in_array($item,$langs_array)){   // If the teach_array value doesn't exist in the lang_array, add the value
    $new_array[] = $item;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it returns the unchaged $teach_array. This is really weird

Comment: @Viteazul var_dump your language array before you do the array_diff and make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: @Viteazul Make sure your array has the correct data with print_r, maybe some weird typecasting is going on?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I did the var_dump and I have some empty spaces in the results of each of my elements. I don't know if that is the problem

Comment: Yeah, that would keep the values from matching. You can array_map trim over that array before comparing to remove the extra spaces.

Comment: @Don'tPanic How would the code look, sorry i'm still learning

Comment: `$result = array_diff($teachArray, array_map('trim', $langsarray));`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure theres a more elegant way, but this works:

```
$teach = [1, 2, 3,4, 5];
$langs = [2, 3];

$result = [];

foreach ($teach as $key => $t) {
    if (!in_array($t, $langs)) {
        $result[$key] = $t;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is (basically) what you say you have. It works for me:

```
<?php
  $fred = array(0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>5);
  $bert = array(0=>2, 1=>3);
  $res = array_diff($fred, $bert);
  print_r($res);
```